# A little bit confused about a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find $A\in M_2(\mathbb{N} )$ so that $A^2-8A+7I_2=O_2$.
What buggs me is that the eigenvalues of $A$ must satisfy the equation $\lambda^2-8\lambda+7=0$,so $A$'s eigenvalues are $1$ and $7$. However, $A=I_2$ also satisfies the equation. So what I don't understand is why my approach is wrong.

Comment: they must satisfy the equation, but necessarily are $1$ and $7$, any combination of  these eigenvalues works just fine

Comment: The eigenvalues must satisfy the equation. They need not include all the solutions of the equation.

Comment: I think I got it : $A$ need not have both $1$ and $7$ as eigenvalues simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is not correct.

If $A^2-8A+7I_2=O_2$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $\lambda^2 - 8\lambda + 7$.

So, any matrix with the minimal polynomial $\lambda - 1$ or $\lambda -7$ will satisfy the above matrix equation.

So, specifically $A=I_2$ will satisfy above equation (as $A = 7I_2$ as well).